# How to resolve my DNS servers

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn, aws

I have setup an AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu Server).

This is the content of /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
```

now I connect my EC2 instance to a VPN, using OpenVPN. OpenVPN make the following changes to /etc/resolv.conf

```
#
# Generated by OpenVPN 3 Linux (NetCfg::DNS::ResolvConfFile)
# Last updated: 2020-08-25 21:39:32
#
search somenetwork.com ap-southeast-2.compute.internal

# OpenVPN defined name servers
nameserver 121.98.0.1
nameserver 20.92.1.1
nameserver 20.92.1.2
nameserver 20.92.1.3

# System defined name servers
nameserver 127.0.0.53

# Other system settings
options edns0
```

After connecting to the VPN, my internet stops working. How can I resolve this issue?

**Update:**

As suggested in the comment by Thomas Ward, I connected to the VPN (which adds the above named server lines to resolv.conf) and then I am not able to browse the internet... but I can still ping 8.8.8.8. If I comment out the lines from resolv.conf then I can start browsing the internet.

I also tried the suggestion in the answer by Ravindra Bagale and ran the command:

```
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
```

this is the output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 openvpn openvpn 244 Oct 10 05:05 /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: your VPN not working is more a problem with the VPN.  If the VPN is set to route all traffic over it INCLUDING your Internet, but the VPN on the other side isn't configured to let you go out to the Internet without restriction you wil run into these kinds of issues.  Are you able to ping things like 8.8.8.8 over the VPN?  Or do you just get an issue with DNS resolution when you're on the VPN?

Comment: @ThomasWard: thanks for your comment, I tried and I can ping 8.8.8.8 (I have updated my question)

Comment: @ThomasWard: If I delete those lines from resolve.conf, does it mean that I am still connected to the VPN but the internet connection does not go through the VPN? I don't want the internet connection to go through VPN, I just want to have access to the resources inside the VPN.

Comment: resolv.conf doesn't control your routes (what actually handles going to the Internet).  IF you don't know the IP ranges on the remote side of the VPN that yo uwant to pass over the VPN (and set static routes for it) you won't be able to have INternet access.  It sounds less like an Internet issue and more the DNS records oyu're receiving from the VPN are bad.  Replace the OPenVPN defnied nameservers with just `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
It happens if you have symbolic link .
```

Check if your `/etc/resolv.conf` have symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

Use below command to check

```
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
```

Sample output, if it has symbolic link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 09 Oct 30 22:22 resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Otherwise, delete or backup existing `/etc/resolv.conf` and then:

```
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I ran the command that you suggest and added the output to the question.